# Relationships between PODs and VLANs and re

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking to confirm if the vlanNumber is unique to a specific POD? My assumption is that I could have a vlanNumber 802 in wdc01.pod5a and another VLAN with the same number in potentially wdc01.pod1a. Is that correct?

I am trying to figure out what the relationship between PODs and VLANs; what is the best API calls to get the list of VLANs in a specific POD. Right now it seems that I can only map VLAN -> SUBNET to POD and not VLAN to POD directly. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

the numbers are unique. Use this RESTFul rquest:

```
GET https://$USERID:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[id,vlanNumber,primaryRouter[id,hostname,datacenter]]

note: Replace $USERID and $APIKEY
```

The request aboce will return all the VLANs in your account the POD they belong and their location

Answer (score 0):

The VLANs are unique to a POD, but more specifically to the POD public or private network.

You can have two VLAN 802 in a POD... one on the public network and one on the private network.